# Solving a vector equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the equation:

$\mathbf{k} \times \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}$.

$\mathbf{k}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are known and I need to find the components of A.

As it stands this system is indeterminate. I choose $\mathbf{k}.\mathbf{A} = 0$, and $\mathbf{B}.\mathbf{A} = 0$ and $|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{A}| = |\mathbf{B}|$ give me three equations for three unknowns. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Once you choose $k \cdot A = 0$, the system is fully determined.

$$A = \hat k (\hat k \cdot A) - \hat k \times (\hat k \times A)$$

You already know $\hat k \times A$, and you set $\hat k \cdot A = 0$, so you're done.  In some higher level stuff (clifford algebra), this decomposition follows from the invertibility of a product that unitifies the dot and cross products, and so it becomes a touch more apparent.

Comment: Why do you write $\mathbf{k}$ as a unit vector with the cap? Does it need to have unit magnitude for this to work?

Comment: That is what this decomposition applies to.

Comment: Is this a standard decomposition that I can find a reference for? Thanks...

Comment: See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_and_normal_components (which describes the decomposition in terms of relations with a surface, and so what they call "parallel" means "parallel to the surface").